# Plot graph near zero

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to plot the following function with Ti*k*Z.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,
    declare function={ 
        func(\z) =  1/(2*(abs(\z)^3)) * (
           (1+abs(\z)) - 2*ln(1+abs(\z)) - 1/(1+abs(\z))
        );
    }
]
```

The problem occurs near zero, the function isn't plotted the right way.

Comment: I edited your question a bit so that it is easier for readers to understand your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way that produces some plot that is reasonably close to the "true" result is to insert the Taylor expansion of the function for smallish `x`. Otherwise Ti*k*Z will evaluate first the `1/x^3` piece and complain. The Taylor expansion, on the other hand shows that there is no singularity. A true computer algebra system would do the limits on its own, but TeX is not such a computer algebra system.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7,
    declare function={ 
        func(\z)=ifthenelse(abs(\z)>0.251, 1/(2*(abs(\z)^3)) * (
           (1+abs(\z)) - 2*ln(1+abs(\z)) - 1/(1+abs(\z))),
           1/6 - abs(\z)/4 + (3*abs(\z)^2)/10 - abs(\z)^3/3 + (5*abs(\z)^4)/14);
    }
]
 \begin{axis}

 \addplot[domain=-1:1,samples=31,smooth]  {func(x)};
 \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]